# How can I create download button for the file from third-party url?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, download

I have a music download button. As you can see, my music files are kept in aws s3 cloud.

```
<a href={`https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/songs/name.mpeg`} download={"Name.mpeg"}>
```

In this case after clicking button I move to the new tab with the music file, and download is not triggered.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/emPT3.jpg

What can I do if I want trigger download after clicking the button immediately?

P.S. I use NodeJS server

P.S.S. Download triggers in Chrome but not in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do it like that

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="filename">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

Comment: Does not work, download is not triggered but opens tab with file instead